# How to read Excel cell data in HTML format in Django

Tags: python, django, xlsx

how to read below excel cell data

Country: **India**

State: **Karnataka**

into

```
<p>Country:<strong> India</strong><br /> State:<strong> Karnataka</strong></p>
```

in Python Django?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643996/upload-data-via-excel-sheet-using-django-excel

Comment: Did you see this?

https://pypi.org/project/django-excel/